# Transformation of Non-Continuous Height Variable

Tags: stata, transformation

I have trouble efficiently transforming a wrongly coded height variable in my sample.

The variable is coded as follows:

```
     Height 
ID1    601   
ID1    601   
ID1    601   
ID3    409   
ID3    410   
ID4    511
.      .
.      .
.      .
ID100  400
```

As you can see, the variable is coded as feet and inch simultaneously where `601` equals 6 foot 1 inch, `511` equals 5 ft 11 inches etc.

My goal is to transform these numbers into inches:

```
replace Height = 48 if Height == 400 
replace Height = 49 if Height == 401
replace Height = 50 if Height == 402
replace Height = 51 if Height == 403
.
.
.
replace Height = 83 if Height == 611
```

How do I efficiently code this with a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below assumes that each observation of `Height` contains exactly three digits:

```
tostring Height, generate(Height_string)
    /* Generate a new variable which is a string-version of Height
       (so that we can get the individual digits) */

generate feet = substr(Height_string, 1, 1)
    /* From the first character in the string, select one character */

generate inch = substr(Height_string, 2, 2)
    /* From the second character in the string, select two characters.
       An equivalent alternative would have been
       generate inch = substr(Height_string, -2, 2)
       which from the second to last character selects two characters */

destring feet inch, replace
    /* Convert these two new variables to numeric */

generate tot_inch = feet * 12 + inch
    /* Generate a new variable which measure only in inches. */
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line as a purely numeric operation. Converting to string and back again is quite unnecessary. No loop is needed.

```
generate wanted = 12 * floor(height/100) + mod(height, 100)
```